# How to make the bottom part of Inno Setup pages transparent? (screenshot given)

Tags: inno-setup, transparent

How can I make an Inno Setup installer like this:

[image]

I mean, I want to make the bottom part of Inno Setup pages like the above image.

What Pascal coding should I use?

Thanks. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way is to obtain [`iswin7.dll`](https://mega.nz/#!B0wl2YKa!n4UyzLSwI-lb_mDmLYCNwZ7R4GiQjFZ5ij78yRHbagI) library from the internet and use it with following code:

```pascal
[Files]
Source: ".\ISWin7.dll"; DestDir: "{tmp}"; Flags: dontcopy nocompression

[Code]
procedure iswin7_add_glass(Handle:HWND; Left, Top, Right, Bottom : Integer; GDIPLoadMode: boolean);
    external 'iswin7_add_glass@files:iswin7.dll stdcall';
procedure iswin7_add_button(Handle:HWND);
    external 'iswin7_add_button@files:iswin7.dll stdcall';
procedure iswin7_free;
    external 'iswin7_free@files:iswin7.dll stdcall';

procedure InitializeWizard();
begin
    iswin7_add_button(WizardForm.BackButton.Handle);
    iswin7_add_button(WizardForm.NextButton.Handle);
    iswin7_add_button(WizardForm.CancelButton.Handle);
    iswin7_add_glass(WizardForm.Handle, 0, 0, 0, ScaleY(47), True);
end;

procedure DeinitializeSetup();
begin
    iswin7_free;
end;
```

Keep in mind that `iswin7.dll` is non-official.

Comment: Thanks! This was exactly what I wanted, but I had added some branding text at the bottom part, now its invisible. Here is my code: http://pastebin.com/CPXZFu9j  So, any way to make it visible again?

Comment: @the_Ma5TeR - not really with the Aero as it will look pretty ugly there. The text background will not be transparent or the text stroke will look bad. However it could look not that bad if you would create new button with your 'branding text' and set custom size and position (button can be either Enabled (displaying MsgBox e.g. with full info) or can be Disabled).

Comment: For text drawing on a sheet of glass you should use the `DrawThemeTextEx` function for which you'd need to intercept the wizard form's window proc. Anyway, once you have that intercept, the rest of this Aero glass stuff consists from two functions, `DwmIsCompositionEnabled` and `DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea`.