# How to make my installer slightly transparent

Tags: inno-setup

Im trying to make my installer slightly transparent using "SetLayeredWindowAttributes", but when i run this code nothing happens to the installer.

```
[setup]
AppName=Transparent
AppVerName=1.0
DefaultDirName={pf}\program

[Files]
Source: "Untitled.png"; DestDir: {tmp}; Flags: ignoreversion dontcopy nocompression

[Code]
function SetLayeredWindowAttributes(
  hwnd: HWND;
  crKey: TColor;
  bAlpha: BYTE;
  dwFlags: DWORD
): Boolean;
external 'SetLayeredWindowAttributes@user32.dll stdcall';

Const
TransparentPercent = 20;
LWA_COLORKEY = 1;

procedure InitializeWizard();
begin
 SetLayeredWindowAttributes(WizardForm.Handle, clLime,(255 * TransparentPercent) / 100, LWA_COLORKEY);
end;
```

How do I make my installer slightly transparent in Inno Setup?

Comment: Why? Installer is not the kind of application that should be transparent.

Comment: Anyway, see http://stackoverflow.com/q/27031922/850848