# Semi-Transparent Wizard Form

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

I was working on an Inno Setup design when I faced this mighty question in front of me...How to make the Wizard form semi-transparent?

I know Delphi too so I'm thinking if there is any way we can use FMX's `Fill.Color` and `transparency=true` with Inno Setup?

I'm currently using this function for Wizard creation:

```pascal
procedure CreateWizardForm;
begin
  with WizardForm do begin
    BorderStyle:=bsNone;
    ClientWidth:=900;
    ClientHeight:=540;
    InnerNotebook.Hide;
    OuterNotebook.Hide;
    Center;
    Bevel.Hide;
    NextButton.Width:=0;
    CancelButton.Width:=0;
  end;

  Form:=ImgLoad(WizardForm.Handle,ExpandConstant('{tmp}')+'\form.png',0,0,900,540,True,True);
end;
```

Regards
Ramiro

Comment: See also [How to make the bottom part of Inno Setup pages transparent? (screenshot given)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27031922/850848)

Comment: Inno Setup is not based on FMX, but VCL.

Answer (score 1):

There is Inno Setup plug-in as for NSIS called [IsWin7](https://www.dropbox.com/s/w5io4l0nikmcmny/ISWin7.dll?dl=0) or [MegaFileUpload](http://www.megafileupload.com/j35k/ISWin7.dll).

It works for Windows Vista and Windows 7 - both systems support Aero effects.

Keep in mind that `iswin7.dll` is non-official.
Sample:

```pascal
[Files]
Source: ".\ISWin7.dll"; DestDir: "{tmp}"; Flags: dontcopy nocompression

[Code]
procedure iswin7_add_glass(Handle:HWND; Left, Top, Right, Bottom : Integer; GDIPLoadMode: boolean);
   external 'iswin7_add_glass@files:iswin7.dll stdcall';
procedure iswin7_add_button(Handle:HWND);
   external 'iswin7_add_button@files:iswin7.dll stdcall';
procedure iswin7_free;
   external 'iswin7_free@files:iswin7.dll stdcall';

procedure InitializeWizard();
begin
   iswin7_add_button(WizardForm.BackButton.Handle);
   iswin7_add_button(WizardForm.NextButton.Handle);
   iswin7_add_button(WizardForm.CancelButton.Handle);
   iswin7_add_glass(WizardForm.Handle, 0, 0, 0, ScaleY(47), True);
end;

procedure DeinitializeSetup();
begin
    iswin7_free;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the feature you are trying to achieve called **Aero** (from Windows Vista)?

I think this is not possible to do in pure Inno Setup.

[image: Aero]

Check this NSIS plug-in: http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Aero_plug-in.
It is open source and uses some Windows API functions -- for inspiration.

Comment: There is such plugin for Inno, but it will work only for Vista and 7.